# При запуске установочного файла `vs_enterprise` ничего не происходит!

Tags: visual-studio-2015, установка, windowsinstaller

Установил `vs_enterprise_ENU` и языковый пакет `vs_langpack`(rus).
Потом решил переустановить `Visual Studio 2015` на диск `/D:`.

Для этого сначала удалил `языковый пакет`, 
затем `VS2015`, 
затем удалил все компоненты которые были установлены вместе с `VS2015` (`.NET Framework`, `visual c++ 2015 redistributable`, `Silverlight`, и т.д.),
а дальше решил удалить оставшиеся на диске `/C:` папки/файлы связанные с `VS`.

И наконец-то приступил к установке `VS2015` на диск `/D:`, но тут и появляется проблема.
После запуска установочного файла буквально на долю секунды появляется окошко VS и все, дальше ничего не происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно я удалил лишние папки/файлы!?
Остальные инсталяторы запускаются нормально.
Моя OS: Windows 10, x64

Выполнял команды: `msiexec /unregister`, `msiexec /regserver`. Перезагрузка. Не помогло!

Выполнил [проверку целостности файлов Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAK9C.png):

- cmd (в режиме администратора) → sfc /scannow → перезагрузка;
- cmd (в режиме администратора) → dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth →
  перезагрузка.

Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Долго игрался и так ничего не получилось. В результате [вернул компьютер в исходное положение](http://remontka.pro/reset-windows-10/), и после `VS2015` установилась без проблем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.